# Partial form in angular 5 validation and processing

Tags: angular, validation, angular5, custom-validators

I have this form in parent component that process purchased items:

parent.component.ts:

```
this.rForm = fb.group({
      'processedon' : [null, [Validators.required,dateIsBeforeOrOnToday2]],

    'supplied_items_info':fb.group({

              'item_manf':[null,[Validators.required]],
              'item_brand':[null,[Validators.required]]
        })

    });
```

the supplied_items_info elements are also repeated in another form:

```
this.rForm2 = fb.group({


    'supplied_items_info':fb.group({

              'item_manf':[null,[Validators.required]],
                'item_brand':[null,[Validators.required]]
        })

    });
```

I wanted to take the it out to a child component and define it there:

child.component.ts

```
   import { Validators,FormControl,ControlContainer, FormGroupName,FormGroup  } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-items-form',

  viewProviders: [
    { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupName  }
  ]
})


          item_brand = new FormControl('',
               [Validators.required]);
          item_manf= new FormControl('',
               [Validators.required]);
```

and insert them in the parent.component.html file:

```
      <div formGroupName="supplied_item_info">
                  <app-item-form></app-item-form>
                  </div>
```

The issue is now I didn't really solve the problem as the parent.component.ts must still define the form fields. How can I define the item elements in a child component and inject them into a parent component so validation takes place in the child form but data is then submitted as part of the parent form?

Comment: To all those who might s[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859538/reuse-individual-angular-5-reactive-form-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859538/reuse-individual-angular-5-reactive-form-elements) and it works great indeed

Answer (score 0):

First bind reusable formcontrols in a method and you can access that method in parent component using @ViewChild decorator.

Here's an example:

child.component.ts

```
     import { Validators,FormControl,ControlContainer, FormGroupName,FormGroup  } from '@angular/forms';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-items-form'
        })

    export class ChildComponent implements OnInit{

      @Input() childFormGroup: FormGroup;

       controls(){
         let controls = {
          'item_manf':[null,Validators.required],
          'item_brand':[null,Validators.required]
         }
         return controls;
       }

    }
```

child.component.html

```
 <div [formGroup]="childFormGroup">
       <input type="text" formControlName="item_brand">
       <input type="text" formControlName="item_manf">
    </div>
```

and use Input decorator to send data from parent to child

parent.component.html:

```
<app-item-form #child [childFormGroup]="rForm.controls.supplied_items_info"></app-item-form>
```

parent.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('child') childComponent: any;

this.rForm = fb.group({
      'processedon' : [null, [Validators.required,dateIsBeforeOrOnToday2]],

    'supplied_items_info':fb.group(this.childComponent.controls())

    });
```

Same way use in multiple forms wherever needed this reusable formControls.

Comment: Thanks @Aniket Avhad : but it is saying cannot ready property "controls" of undefined.

Comment: Initialize formControls on ngOnInit(), don't initialize in constructor. bcoz before initalize contols there view need to be initilaize.